# ¿Cómo logro hacer que mi código en c++ tome únicamente ciertos valores específicos?

Tags: c++

Si tengo un archivo de entrada con los números

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Necesito que imprima el primero en consola, el segundo en el archivo de salida, el tercero en la consola y el cuarto en el archivo de salida. No logro entender como hacerlo. Llevo el código anterior, pero lógicamente saca todos los números del arreglo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fi("input.txt");
    ofstream fo("output.txt");

    int a;
    int array[100];
    int i=0;

    if(fi.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo leer el archivo"<<endl;
    }else{
       while(fi>>a){
            fo<<a<<endl;
            array [i]=a;
              i++;
       }
    }
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
        cout<<array[j]<<endl;
    }
    fi.close(); fo.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes, primero llenar el Array, y luego mirar si su posición es par o impar para decidir que hacer con su contenido. Algo parecido a esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fi("input.txt");
    ofstream fo("output.txt");

    int a;
    int array[100];
    int i=0;

    if(fi.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo leer el archivo"<<endl;
    }else{
       while(fi>>a){
            array[i]=a;
            i++;
       }
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
            if (j%2==0) cout<<array[j]<<endl; // Posiciones pares
            else fo<<array[j]<<endl; // Posiciones impares
        }
    }
    fi.close(); fo.close();

    return 0;
}
```

(Edit: he arreglado alguna cosa mas, como escribir la salida solo en caso de leer la entrada)

Por cierto, evidentemente el programa fallará si el input contiene mas de 100 valores. En este problema en concreto creo que seria mejor usar los valores a medida que se leen, en vez de llenar una matriz, algo parecido a esto:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fi("input.txt");
    if(fi.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo leer el archivo"<<endl;
    }else{
        ofstream fo("output.txt");
        bool esPar=true;
        int valor;
        while(fi>>valor){
            if (esPar) cout<<valor<<endl;
            else fo<<valor<<endl;
            esPar=!esPar;
        }
        fo.close();
    }
    fi.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Prueba esto:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream fi("input.txt");
    std::ofstream fo("output.txt");

    if (fi.is_open())
    {
        std::string linea;
        for (int indice = 0; std::getline(fi, linea); ++indice)
        {
            (!(indice % 2) ? std::cout : fo) << linea;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Tanto la salida de consola ([`std::cout`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)) como la salida a archivo ([`std::ofstream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)) son *streams* de salida de datos (heredan de [`std::basic_ostream`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), así que ambos disponen del operador de inyección de datos ([`std::basic_ostream::operator <<`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt))), así que en la instrucción:

```
(!(indice % 2) ? std::cout : fo) << linea;
```

Seleccionamos la salida a consola o a archivo en base a si la variable `indice` es par o impar usando el [operador ternario](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) y le inyectamos el dato leído del archivo de entrada mediante [`std::getline`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Date cuenta que no cierro los *streams*, ya que éstos se cierran automáticamente al finalizar el programa. Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uha4aLyxJXlQ4e1V)</kbd>.